# VMPlayer with Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS as guest on Win10 host show sometimes VERY high load on Xorg

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, ubuntu-20.04, xorg, vmware-player

I have a development VM with Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (5.15.0-69-generic all updates installed) running in a VMPlayer 17.0.1 on Win10 host. 6 of 8 CPU cores are assigned to the VM and 10 (of 16) GB of RAM.

My problem: sometimes the load of Xorg rises upto 80%, eating up nearly a whole CPU rendering the VM system to be nearly inresponsive.

I have two shells running with remote "top" and remote "iotop", the grafical system monitor and Eclipse (latest) with moderate text output (of some C++ service under CDT) that most time itself requests high CPU power. All in all the screen activities are quite low.

I found a lot of tips, but all refereing to WIN hosted on Ubuntu ... I have it the other way: Linux hosted on Win10. So I cannot use all these tips like `vblank_mode=0 vmware´.

What can I do to decrese that load of Xorg? Switching off 3D accelleration is no option as I need that often for checking the result of the developed service.

What additional infos can I deliver to allow helping hints?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it took me a while. The question is 5 months old but I leave it here, hope this will help someone.

In my case the problem was NVIDIA configuration on host machine.

What I did:
Open "NVIDIA Control Panel" -> "Manage 3d settings" -> "Preferred graphics processor". I changed from "Auto-select" to "High-performance NVIDIA processor" & reboot.

Now my Xorg is using stable 1-3% CPU.